# Minipage inside environment showing irregular behaviour

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, minipage

I am working on this template for my CV: https://www.overleaf.com/read/fjwccvybcphp#9f38d9. In main, you have

```
\input{Txt/1-CV-body}\input{Txt/p1_sidebar}\clearpage\input{Txt/2-page2}\input{Txt/p2_Sidebar}
```

which creates two minipages side by side on page 1, but the same minipages are vertically stacked on page 2. How can I fix this irregular behaviour on page 2?

Here, 1-CV-body and 2-page2 use the CVbody environment, whereas p1_sidebar and p2_Sidebar have the CVsidebar environment.

CV.cls has the following code:

```
\newenvironment{CVsidebar}{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}\raggedright
    }{%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
\newenvironment{CVbody}{%
        \hspace{-0.5cm}\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}\raggedright
    }{%
        \end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}
    }%
```

The first image shows page 1, with the intended behaviour:

[image: Page 1]

The second image shows page 2, with the unintended behaviour:

[image]

Some attempts include adding many vertical breaks (crashes as it is hard-coded to remain under 2 pages). Enabling multipleCVs pushes it onto the 3rd page.

Comment: Questions should be self-containing. External links can break and also not be available for some. So please try to extend your code snippets to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). This would also increase your chance to get an answer. However, as you have an empty line between `\input{Txt/2-page2}` and `\input{Txt/p2_Sidebar}` and empty lines in LaTeX are `\par`, it is expected, that the content of the two files is stacked vertical. You should remove the empty line 110. But I've not tested it.

Comment: A minipage is positioned like a letter. XX come side by side, X blank line X come vertically stacked and X X may do either depending if the line breaks at the space

Comment: @cabohah I have gotten rid of all empty spaces, but the problem persists.